# Trying to make a boolean list in python

Tags: python, list, boolean

I need to make a list in python that lists all numbers from 0 to N as true initially. I have to use
def shake(alist):

I tried some other code but I was informed that I didnt create a boolean list where everything was true, I had just calculated the numbers which ends up being wrong. I am supposed to create this list where the values are all true, and then make it where I set up all the integer values are false that are multiples of prime numbers and then print off a list of the remaining true values. I am stuck on how to even begin with this because I havent seen anything like this before. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You should show us your wrong code.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> N = 10
>>> [True] * N
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, to create list with true values, you can use list comprehension:

```
lst = [True for _ in range(N)]
```

or use the fact, that all non-zero integers evaluate to True in bool context:

```
lst = map(bool, range(1, N+1))
```

Later you can operate on this list. To change some values to `False` (just remember, that first index is `0` ;).

If you get stuck again, please show some code, you have so far, along with input/expected output. Good luck.